# AngularJS run service function before other functions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am new to AngularJS and have a service that loads my initial user configuration

```
angular.module('myApp').service('myService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var self = this;
    self.user = {};

    self.loadConfiguration = function () {
        $http.get('/UserConfig').then(function (result) {
            self.user = result.data;
        });
    };

    self.loadConfiguration();
}]);
```

I have a controller that uses the configuration from this service

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
    var self = this;

    // calculation based on service value
    self.something = myService.user.something * something else;
}]);
```

The problem here is that myService.user.something may be undefined since the AJAX request may not have completed when this code is called. Is there a way to have the service complete before any other code is run? I want the service function 'loadConfiguration' to be run only once irrespective of the number of controllers that depend on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to make sure that your code in controller gets executed after your AJAX call returns, you may use events.

Use this in your service:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('myService', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    var self = this;
    self.user = {};

    self.loadConfiguration = function () {
        $http.get('/UserConfig').then(function (result) {
            self.user = result.data;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('myService:getUserConfigSuccess');
        });
    };

    self.loadConfiguration();
}]);
```

In your controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
    var self = this;

    $scope.$on('myService:getUserConfigSuccess', function() {
        // calculation based on service value
        self.something = myService.user.something * something else;
    })
}]);
```

You can even attach an object to the event.

Please refer to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope .

Comment: Your answer mostly works. It does not work if the service has already loaded before the controller is initialized because then the $scope.$on('myService:getUserConfigSuccess') will never fire.

Comment: @user1 Ahhhh, yes! So if you wanna make sure, you can either call `loadConfiguration()` from your controller, or add a check of if `user` already loaded in the controller (if yes, use it; if no, add a event listener).

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended up doing. :) I wanted to leave a record of the accepted answer's shortcoming to help out anyone reading this several months from now.

Comment: I liked this solution actually of the two i came across you can check this solution too .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475825/angular-controller-runs-before-run-angularjs ... But in this scenario now i have around 50 controllers, all controller need some data from the function that runs at service level ,, am i expected to wrap all my controller block in side the event handler :( Is there any alternative..

Comment: @BlackBurn027 You may have a look at rxjs https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS

Answer (score 6):

You can call your service method inside `.run()` function

> **Run Blocks**
>
> Run blocks are the closest thing in Angular to the main
>   method. A run block is the code which needs to run to kickstart the
>   application. It is executed after all of the service have been
>   configured and the injector has been created. Run blocks typically
>   contain code which is hard to unit-test, and for this reason should be
>   declared in isolated modules, so that they can be ignored in the
>   unit-tests.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

```
angular.module('myApp').run(function()){
   //use your service here
}
```

One way to deal with ajax delay, is use `$rootScope.$broadcast()` function on $http.success which will broadcast your custom event to all controllers. Antoher way is to use promises and perform actions in controllers after resolve. Here are some ideas: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/qagzXXhS_VI/discussion

Comment: Best Choice! ^^ Thank You for the help:)